In Odoo 17, set complex logic in xml domain
I need to update the logic of an existing action domain in the standard Odoo 17 mrp module:
<record id="mrp.action_mrp_production_moves" model="ir.actions.act_window">

to be:
move_id.raw_material_production_id=active_id
OR
move_id.production_id=active_id
OR
(   # If the above (of owner move) are not set, then check `line.production_id` as well
move_id.raw_material_production_id=False
AND
move_id.production_id=False
AND
production_id=active_id
)


This is the answer I found working after understanding the syntax of the logic needed:
<odoo>
    <data>
        <!-- Update existing action record -->
        <record id="mrp.action_mrp_production_moves" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field
                name="domain">['|',
                ('move_id.raw_material_production_id', '=',active_id),
                '|',
                ('move_id.production_id', '=', active_id),
                '&amp;',
                ('move_id.raw_material_production_id','=',False),
                '&amp;',
                ('move_id.production_id', '=', False),
                ('production_id', '=',active_id),
                ]</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>

Here is the explanation of this complex domain syntax:

Understanding it starts from the end.
| and & take only two "terms", not more. So, the "expression" is always an operator that has (precedes) two following "terms". A "term" can be a simple one (,,) or an expression.
For |A|B&C&DE, it's evaluated as following (from the end):

&DE: D & E => As X
&CX: C & X = C & (D & E) => As 'Y'
|BY: B | Y = B | (C & (D & E)) => As 'Z'
|AZ: A | (B | (C & (D & E)))




This should be domain as you wanted:
    <field name="domain">[
    '|', '|',
    ('move_id.raw_material_production_id', '=', context.get('active_id')),
    ('move_id.production_id', '=', context.get('active_id')),
    '&', '&',
    ('move_id.raw_material_production_id', '=', False),
    ('move_id.production_id', '=', False),
    ('production_id', '=', context.get('active_id'))]
</field>

